# Creating iPad applications faster

Tags: iphone

I'm new to iPad application development, but I am an experienced Web application developer in ASP.net. I want to develop fine applications for the iPad, but I want to learn from scratch.

Please suggest me some online tutorial links or guide me through the right path for starting and learning development faster. I have less time and have to learn and develop more.